# Laptop fails to resume from hibernation (suspend to disk) after update to 18.04

Tags: suspend, power-management, 18.04, hibernate

For the beginning i say, that hibernation worked perfect on 17.10 on my hardware, and it doesn't look to me as a hardware problem now. Now when i'm putting my laptop to hibernation either by `systemctl hibernate` or `hibernate` it does write memory content somewhere on the disk, but while i'm starting it again, it looks like the kernel or initrd can't find the proper hibernation image. What i tried:

Put `RESUME=UUID=cac3c850-bc33-44ab-adb4-41dcb5403e6f` into my `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`, and do `update-initramfs -u`, this actually made things worse, because it just made the boot slower and i had to wait until it will say "giving up on resume" or something like that. The UUID is correct, i checked with `blkid`, and i use this as a swap partition, checked with `swapon --show`.

I tried to remove it from `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and add resume=UUID=cac3c850-bc33-44ab-adb4-41dcb5403e6f to `/etc/default/grub`, and do `update-grub`, and also checked that it has been passed to kernel by `cat /proc/cmdline`, but also no luck. So how can I make ubuntu 18.04 resume after suspend? Or at least how can i debug issue more, to find out what's the problem exactly?

Comment: It's probably a kernel bug. Have you tried booting with previous kernels? Hold shift after the startup and select a previous kernel to start with. If hibernation worked on that remove the new kernel and kernel header.

Comment: Well, i will try, but what setup should i use? the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`, or kerel cmdline? U use 4.17.0-rc4 kernel.

Comment: @SadeghGhasemi, trying other kernels didn't help, i think the bug is somewhere in initramfs-tools, maybe it looks for hibernate image somewhere else, but i have no idea how to debug it.

Comment: Did you try adding `resume=/dev/your/swap/path/here` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`? (don’t forget to run `update-grub` after) I had the same problem as you, and that’s all I needed to do to get hibernate working in 18.04 (other than making my swap partition large enough).

Comment: yes, i tried. Also, what hibernation software should i use? `systemctl hibernate`? `hibernate`? `pm-hibernate`? Which one? Or they all doing the same?What do you mean by large enough? I have 16gb of memory, but 8gb of swap, but it wasn't the issue for resuming before, all it may do - not to suspend, if swap isn't enough, bot now it goes to suspend and never resumes.

Comment: @user2819650 Use `systemctl hibernate`, and if you have 16GB of RAM, you need at least 16GB of swap.

Comment: Well theat's what i do, and does hibernate, but can't resume.